# How to implement social authentication for an API?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, express

I am building an API in Node.js that will eventually interact with a web interface written in Angular and a mobile app as well. What authentication method can I use to ensure that these login options are available from both the web interface and the app?

Comment: Hello, you can use this angular plugin. https://github.com/heresy/angularjs-social-login. Support Google+, Facebook and Linked In.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the perfect solution: [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)