# Angular2 Google sign

Tags: angular, typescript, google-api, google-api-js-client, angular2-modules

Hi I'm trying Angular2 with Type Script to add a login/logout to/from google by [their guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

In Index.html

```
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

In LoginComponent.ts

```
declare const gapi: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  gapi.signin2.render(
  this.googleLoginButtonId,
  {"onSuccess": this.onGoogleLoginSuccess,"scope": "profile",
    "theme": "dark"},function (error) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
  });
```

}

```
      onGoogleLoginSuccess = (loggedInUser) => {
var profile = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile();
       this.auth.LoginSuccess(loggedInUser);
      }
```

Thats works fine for me but when loginSuccess i want to route the view to profile page on that time i am facing the error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at G_ (cb=gapi.loaded_0:282)
    at H_.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:285)
    at Function.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:155)
    at MessagePort.c.port1.onmessage (cb=gapi.loaded_0:73)
```

And Also i want the whole login process As Service Or Module to reuse. How Can I create This Whole Google Login Operations As Module or service

Can U give me a code snippet or working demos or suggest me any angular2 module to achieve this.

I also Tried angular2SocialLogin Module But That Also shows error when the production i got error some think I mention in [git issue](https://github.com/heresy/angular2-social-login-example/issues/1#issuecomment-285268190)

Please Help Me Out of it .Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can be fixed by hiding the login button once login is successful.

```
 <div id="g-signin2" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688248/google-throws-cannot-read-property-style-of-null-error-after-login-logout-if)

Also I followed this [plunkr example](http://embed.plnkr.co/n0pFS3y74EpJzwgscrBu/) and worked fine with me

Comment: thank you Thabung but i want google sign in as service or module how can i achieve that pls help me....

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer i found the solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096271/how-to-implement-social-authentication-for-an-api)